# Xpath error due to miscorrected paths

Tags: c#, .net

When i start to debug application i am getting this error Can any one give me the solution

Error   1   The command "xcopy "F:\asoadmin_ML_view\leaf\Console\Bin\Debug\Console.*"  "F:\leafPRODUCT\Bin" /f /e /y /i
xcopy "F:\leafPRODUCT..\voyagerhtml\Operations Sentinel Console Help*.chm" "F:\leafPRODUCT\Help" /f /e /y /i
" exited with code 4.

Comment: Elaborate your question please.

Comment: Does the application call xcopy?

Comment: Is anything need to write in pre-build event commandline in the Buildevent property of project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your build process likely has a pre/post build step associated with it that is executing the XCopy commands.  [Error code 4](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb491035.aspx) implies either insufficient disk space to perform the copy, or a syntax error in the command.

To edit your project's pre/post build steps, right click on your project, then select **Properties** -> **Build Events**.  To diagnose these commands, try running them from the command line after you build your project.

Comment: means i didnt get these words what you mentioned " To diagnose these commands, try running them from the command line after you build your project. "

Comment: Yaa i got it second line producing problems,,Actually the path is not given means  ..\voyagerhtml  here in that ..\ we need to give appropriate folder name

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true), error code 4 means either you do not have enough memory to perform debugging, or (much more likely) you have invalid syntax.  The [answer to this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/b43b6d4c-3799-4617-9b64-d6e2bdf8e57d) suggests placing double quotes around your entire path.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the user with which you try to execute the 'xcopy' doesn't have enough permissions (according to this thread: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/5c4a55e2-243a-427f-800d-39b42c9e860e).